# ¿Cómo crear un arreglo de objetos en PHP?

Tags: php, poo

Estoy aprendiendo php y quiero pasar un programa de otro lenguaje a php y necesito crear un arreglo de la clase "objeto".

```
<?php
    class objeto{
        public $peso;
        public $valor;
        public $valorPeso;
        public $tomado;
    }
    global $objetos[3] = new objeto(); //esta linea da error
    global $solucion = array(); ?>
```

¿como puedo crear un arreglo de la clase "objeto"? lo quiero para iterar después y no encuentro nada claro en internet. me esperaba algo como "struct" en c++.

Comment: La línea indicada te da error porque tienes que hacer un New objeto() por cada uno de los elementos del array.

Answer (score 3):

En PHP para acceder a las propiedades de una clase, se debe hacer lo siguiente:

1. Declaras las propiedades que tienen relación directa con la existencia de la clase, de este modo:

---

```
class Persona
{
    public $name;
    public $age;
}
```

2. Posterior, se pueden inicializar dichas propiedades a través de un método mágico constructor de PHP, que nos ayudará a darle valores a las propiedades cada vez que se haga una nueva instancia de la clase, así:

---

```
class Persona
{
    public $name;
    public $age;

    public function __construct($name, $age)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
    }
}
```

3. Posterior, creamos una nueva instancia de la clase `Persona` de este modo

---

```
$obj = new Persona("valor 1", "valor 2");
```

1. Dentro del proceso de la instanciación le hemos asignado acceso a la clase `Persona` al objeto `$obj`

> Finalmente para poder *iterar* a las propiedades de dicha clase a las cuales ahora podemos acceder a través del objeto `$obj` lo hacemos de este modo

---

```
foreach($obj as $key => $value){
    echo $key."=".$value."<br />";
}
```

- Las propiedades y sus valores dentro del objeto `$obj` ahora forman una estructura de array asociativo; es decir `clave => valor` lo cual podemos comprobar si hacemos esto

---

```
var_dump($obj);
```

Dando este resultado

> object(Persona)#1 (2) { ["name"]=> string(7) "valor 1" ["age"]=> string(7) "valor 2" }

Para poder iterar dichos valores, deberemos usar un bucle de tipo `foreach` de este modo

```
foreach($obj as $key => $value){
    echo $key."=".$value."<br />";
}
```

- Donde descomponemos el array en `$key` y `$value` para poder obtener un resultado de este tipo

> name=valor 1 age=valor 2

**Detalles finales**

- Si observas nuestra clase tiene 2 propiedades, que inicializamos sus valores a través del método `__construct()`
- Para poder iterar sobre dichos valores, creamos primero una instancia de la misma en el objeto `$obj`
- Usamos un bucle `foreach()` para acceder a los valores de las *keys* del array asociativo

Comment: ¿Como se podría utilizar esto para ir "almacenado" resultados de una consulta de Mysql ?